# javascript getting and setting property

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to work with javascript objects, but not getting very far. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

```
function Tracking(){
    var choices = new Array();

}

Tracking.prototype.getChoice = function (key){
    return this.choices[key];
}
Tracking.prototype.setChoice = function (choice){
    this.choices.push[choice];
}   

function TrackingChoice(key, choice){
    this.key = key;
    this.choice = choice;
}
```

.....

```
    var tracking = new Tracking();

    var choices = new Array();
    choices.push(new TrackingChoice("purchase", true));
    choices.push(new TrackingChoice("listing", false));
    choices.push(new TrackingChoice("offers", false));
    choices.push(new TrackingChoice("messages", false));

    tracking.setChoice(choices);


    var a = tracking.getChoice(0);
```

`var a` is empty as the choices array in the `Tracking` object are still null. This confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
   function Tracking(){
    this.choices = []; var count = 0;
    this.getChoice = function (key){
        return this.choices[key];
    };
    this.setChoice = function (choice){
        this.choices[count] = choice;count++;
    };
}
function TrackingChoice(key, choice){
    this.key = key;
    this.choice = choice;
}
var tracking = new Tracking();
var choices = new Array();
tracking.setChoice(new TrackingChoice("purchase", true));
tracking.setChoice(new TrackingChoice("listing", false));
tracking.setChoice(new TrackingChoice("offers", false));
tracking.setChoice(new TrackingChoice("messages", false));
var a = tracking.getChoice(0);
```

Comment: sweet thanks mate but I'm not sure why the .push() didn't work as i use that all the time

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few issues here.

```
function Tracking(){
    var choices = new Array();
}
```

Should be

```
function Tracking(){
    this.choices = new Array();
}
```

Then, push is a function, use `()` not `[]`:

```
this.choices.push(choice);
```

Then your test code is passing an entire array to `setChoice` when that function looks like it sets one item at a time.  So you would push 1 element into the array, which is the entire choices array.  You would probably want to call `setChoice` for each element rather than once.  Though really your `setChoice` should be named `addChoice` as it adds an element, doesn't set the whole array.  I would expect `setChoice` to just reassign the entire array.  It really just depends what you intended that function to really do.

http://jsfiddle.net/unw3R/

Comment: `new Array()` should be `[]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
Tracking.prototype.setChoice = function (choice){
    this.choices.push[choice];
}
```

You are reading the choice property off the push method of the choices array which doesn't really do anything - it will read the property and return it, but it will return `undefined` and that value is not stored or used anywhere.

You instead should set the choices property on `this`:

```
Tracking.prototype.setChoice = function (choice){
    this.choices = choice;
}
```

Check out the [Array.push() method](http://www.javascripture.com/Array#push) for more examples on using the push method correctly.